# Options for creating relationships between the database(sqlite) models. Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I create a connection between the two models of the DB(sqlite) `Operation` and `Contragent`:

```
class Operation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "operation"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    date_operation = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, nullable=True)    
    contragent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contragent.id'))# add db.ForeignKey('contragent.id')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Operation {}>'.format(self.code)


class Contragent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "contragent"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(360))    
    operations = db.relationship('Operation', backref='operation', lazy='dynamic')# add this line

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Contragent {}>'.format(self.name)
```

After I make changes to the models, I create a new database migration and
I apply changes in the database, while getting an error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\testapp>flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade d0ac0532c134 -> 285707aa6265,
Operation table
ERROR [root] Error: No support for ALTER of constraints in SQLite dialect
```

In the `run_migrations_online ()` method of the `env.py` file, I added `render_as_batch = True`,but the error still remains:

```
with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            render_as_batch=True, # add this line
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )
```

After that I tried to set the value of the variable `render_as_batch`:

```
config.get_main_option('sqlalchemy.url').startswith('sqlite:///')
...
with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            render_as_batch=config.get_main_option('sqlalchemy.url').startswith('sqlite:///'), # add this line
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )
....
```

The error still happens!
Why does the error occur even after setting the variable `render_as_batch` with the recommended values ​​and what are the options to make changes to the database model?

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxCK1DkikgA